# DynamoDB Filter-Expression Not Returning Any Results

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, filterexpression

I have a dynamodb table with [one entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGABK.png) Using API gateway I am making a call to a lamda function that should handle the DB requests.When using curl command `curl {api link}/items/test` I don't get any results back even though my lamda function should filter for the username specified. Every other call works. This is the lamda code that is handling the request:

```
switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "GET /items/{username}":
         body = await dynamo.send(
          new ScanCommand({ 
            TableName: tableName,
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {":u": { S: event.pathParameters.username }},
            FilterExpression: "username = :u",
            ProjectionExpression: "username",
          })
        );
        body = body.Item;
        break;
      case "GET /items/{username}/{exercise_name}":
        body = await dynamo.send(
          new GetCommand({
            TableName: tableName,
            Key: {
              username: event.pathParameters.username,
              exercise_name: event.pathParameters.exercise_name
            },
          })
        );
        body = body.Item;
        break;
      case "PUT /items":
        let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
        await dynamo.send(
          new PutCommand({
            TableName: tableName,
            Item: {
              username: requestJSON.username,
              exercise_name: requestJSON.exercise_name,
              records: requestJSON.records,
            },
          })
        );
        body = `Put/Updated item ${requestJSON.exercise_name} for user ${requestJSON.username} `;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
```

Is my filter expression wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

I tried different variations of the filter expression and i was unable to get a result. Variations:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {":u": event.pathParameters.username },
            FilterExpression: "contains(username, :u )"
```

```
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {":u": { "S": event.pathParameters.username }},
            FilterExpression: "username = :u",
```

Comment: Can you share what the item looks like from DynamoDB

Comment: It is linked under the hyperlink 'one entry'. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGABK.png! @LeeroyHannigan

Comment: Change your scan to a GetItem

Comment: Looks like I got it to work. I needed to change body = body.Item to body = body.Items 